# How to convert module.export to es6 export when function has a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I have this old code

```js
const expressSetResHeaderFn = (res, headerName, requestId) => {
  res.set(headerName, requestId)
}

const expressMiddleware = (setResHeaderFn) => {
    return ({
        useHeader = false,
        headerName = 'X-Request-Id',
        requestIdFactory = uuidv1,
        echoHeader = false
    } = {}) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            let requestId;
            if (useHeader) {
                requestId = req.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()];
            }
            requestId = requestId || requestIdFactory(req);

            if (echoHeader) {
                setResHeaderFn(res, headerName, requestId);
            }

            als.run(requestId, () => {
                wrapHttpEmitters(req, res);
                next();
            });
        };
    };
}

module.exports = {
  expressMiddleware: expressMiddleware(expressSetResHeaderFn),
  someotherFuncs,
}
```

Now I want to convert it to es6 style, I tried this but doesn't work

```js
export { 
    expressMiddleware : expressMiddleware(expressSetResHeaderFn), 
    someotherFuncs
}
```

How should I convert above code to es6 style?

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunc = expressMiddleware(expressSetResHeaderFn)
export {
  myFunc as expressMiddleware,
  someotherFuncs
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with this error:`'expressMiddleware' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof expressMiddleware'?`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of export, you should use export default

```
export default {
    expressMiddleware: expressMiddleware(expressSetResHeaderFn),
    someotherFuncs
}
```

Comment: For a bag of random functions, using named exports is a better representation of the purpose of the code.